# nested AlertDialogs in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to display an AlertDialog inside of another AlertDialog. When the user clicks on the any item within the initial AlertDialog another AlertDialog is created and shown.

I'm following the correct pattern for creating and displaying AlertDialogs, the problem is as soon as the code reaches the point where the innerDialog.show() method is encountered the application fails. The logcat prints an uncaught runtime exception:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException : Unable to add window -- token null is not for an applicaion
```

I'm wondering if i'm allowed to call the show() method on the innerAlertDialog manually. 
The outer AlertDialog is working because i'm using the callback onCreateDialog() method.

Comment: Wow...  changed the getApplicationContext() to 'this', now everything seems to be working.... 
I mean i read somewhere to try this but thought that was too naive and has nothing to do with my code. silly me.

Comment: Does someone can explain why passing 'this' is different than passing getApplicationContext() ? Is it the UI thread story ? It can be interesting to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions there was a bug where getApplicationContext() returned null.

I still dont quite if it has been fixed however with dialogs, its always better to send this.

And for the main question, its working as designed to avoid locking the UI thread. 
I have seen people recommending creating a new layout with the theme of the dialog and start the activity on the first dialog, however I havent try this yet.